# Python Typing - Return generic protocol as self

Tags: python, generics, typing

If I have a base class that takes a generic `T` bound to `typing.Protocol`, how do I annotate that this class will be assignable to the passed protocol?

For example:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Protocol, Optional

T = TypeVar("T", bound = Protocol)

class Test(Generic[T]):
    something: Optional[str] = None

    def return_protocol(self) -> T:
        ...
        return self.__class__() # typing error, cannot assign self to T
```

I would like an end API of something like this:

```py
class ProtoThatWrapsTest(Protocol):
    something: str
    ...


class Derived(Test[ProtoThatWrapsTest]):
    ...

t = Test()
t.something # Optional[str]

d = Derived().return_protocol()
d.something # str
```

Comment: Are you trying to subclass the `Generic[T]`  or receive it as a parameter in a constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was as simple as adding `type: ignore` to `return self.__class__()`.